# Why won't results show in order when using count(*) DESC

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get results and list them in order descending by score. Everything works fine except that the last result is not in order for some reason as you can see below. What might be causing this last record from not listing in order?

Name  Score
Jay      19
Chris    12
Locke    1
Mike      3

Here is the relevant code:

```
$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
points.ID,
points.PID,
SUM(points.PID) AS total
FROM points
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON points.ID=wp_users.ID
GROUP BY points.ID ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 4");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want to sort by the total:

```
order by total desc
```

or:

```
order by sum(points.pid) desc
```

The ordering you get is based on the number of matching records, rather than the sum in the output.

Comment: That's it, thanks. For some reason I was thinking that count(*) was essential but the math is all done by SUM. thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.